# Bluray: skip intro button [90% done]

Tags: video, javascript, blu-ray

I have 65 episodes of some animated series in .mp4 h264 that I want to burn onto bluray disc, and I need to have those 2 functions:

- programmable "skip intro" button that (after pressing button) will skip the first 40s of the video, or disappear after 40s.
- and remember last-time watched episode, so I won't be looking for which episode I was playing in previous movie session.

Can you look at this code?

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*; import javax.microedition.media.*; import javax.microedition.media.control.*;

public class SkipIntroButton extends Form implements CommandListener {

private Player player; private Command skipIntroCommand; private Command saveProgressCommand; private long lastPlayedTime;

public SkipIntroButton(Player player) {   super("Skip Intro");   this.player = player;   skipIntroCommand = new Command("Skip Intro", Command.SCREEN, 1);   saveProgressCommand = new Command("Save Progress", Command.SCREEN, 2);   addCommand(skipIntroCommand);   addCommand(saveProgressCommand);   setCommandListener(this); }

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {   if (c == skipIntroCommand) {
    // Get the current episode length from metadata
    long duration = player.getDuration();
    if (duration > 0) {
      // Calculate the time to skip to (40 seconds into the episode)
      long skipTime = 40000;
      if (skipTime > duration) {
        skipTime = duration;
      }
      // Skip to the calculated time
      player.setMediaTime(skipTime);
    }   } else if (c == saveProgressCommand) {
    // Save the current playback time as the last played time
    lastPlayedTime = player.getMediaTime();   } }

// Method to restore playback to the last played time public void restoreProgress() {   player.setMediaTime(lastPlayedTime); }

// Method to hide the form after 40 seconds public void hideAfter40s() {   // Use a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI thread   new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(40000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Do nothing
      }
      // Hide the form
      setVisible(false);
    }   }).start(); } } SkipIntroButton form = new SkipIntroButton(player);

form.hideAfter40s();

form.restoreProgress();
```

1. Do I need Java ME, or Intellij with J2ME plugin?
2. Burning blurays from .mp4 files needs to be done with .iso, right? and if so how do I save my program with .iso?

Comment: start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BD-J#Content_development

Comment: Menus are applied to the image at the time the image is being created, so you need Blu-Ray authoring software that is capable of accepting your java class for menu control.